# No html reports in my target folder

Tags: karate

I have created my first feature and it is running awesome.  However i did not see below kind of html reports in my target folder. Could you please help me on it.`https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/resources/karate-maven-cucumber-reporting.png`

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3):

I think I already asked you to read the documentation a little more carefully in another answer. Anyway, here is the link:

https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#example-report

Add this to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then add a file `src/test/java/log4j2.properties` with the following contents:

```
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, CONSOLE
log4j.appender.CONSOLE = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Refer to the documentation for more details, but use the parallel runner:

```
@Test
public void testParallel() {
    String karateOutputPath = "target/surefire-reports";
    KarateStats stats = CucumberRunner.parallel(getClass(), 5, karateOutputPath);
    generateReport(karateOutputPath);
    assertTrue("there are scenario failures", stats.getFailCount() == 0);        
}

private static void generateReport(String karateOutputPath) {
    Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[] {"json"}, true);
    List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList(jsonFiles.size());
    for (File file : jsonFiles) {
        jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "your-project-name");
    ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
    reportBuilder.generateReports();    
}
```

Comment: I had gone through your documentation and it is awesome. Thanks so much for your help. Could you please let me know whether i need to add below dependencies and configurations as well to pom.xml  .                                              1. org.springframework.boot  2. commons-io ;  3.include>demo/DemoTestParallel.java</include> 4. <cucumber.options>--plugin junit:target/surefire-reports/cucumber-junit.xml</cucumber.options>                                                                         https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/pom.xml

Comment: Right click on DemoTestParallel.java-->  Then I see results of below features in overview-features.html file. My features (jenkins.feature) is not running.                               https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/resources/karate-maven-cucumber-reporting.png

Comment: You seem to be trying to re-use the code of the demo which I already mentioned in another comment is the wrong approach and will confuse you further. Just try to create a project from scratch using the archetype and Joe Colantonio's tutorial. There are more tutorials listed here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Community-News - or please ask someone who knows Java to help you. All the best.

Comment: I was making everything complicated before. I did follow what you said exactly and it is working. Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: @arkadiyala awesome. great to hear that :)

Comment: @arkadiyala do you mind up-voting and accepting the answer ? this helps maintain the quality of Stack Overflow responses.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are looking for cucumber reports.

```
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/java/features"},glue={"stepDef"},format={"pretty", "html:target/Destination"})
```

`format={"pretty", "html:target/Destination"}` specifies the path to the folder you want cucumber html reports to be stored

Comment: I also made things complicated, instead of strictly following the Karate official tutorial. I didn't notice that `@RunWith(Karate.class)` should be removed. It's very simple to implement and very nice. You can hide or show details and 'Doc string` is to discover!!! I finally prefer karate reports than others.

Comment: @Ashish Deshmukh I'm the dev of Karate and I'd like to point out that this answer is wrong. Karate is *NOT* Cucumber.